# WebAPI 2.2 OData v3 Jagged Array empty result

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, odata, geojson

I'm trying to implement a simple WebAPI that returns Data from a class. All data is received correctly exept the jagged string array.
This is the code:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetGetGeoData_Result()
    {
        var results = db.GetGeoData().ToList();

        List<GeoJsonResult> jsonResult = new List<GeoJsonResult>();

        results.ForEach(r => jsonResult.Add(new GeoJsonResult()
        {
            Type = "Feature",
            Geometry = new GeoJsonGeometry()
            {
                Type = r.geo_type,
                Coordinates = this.CalculateCoordinates(r.coordinates) // This result is empty => Jagged string array (string[][])
            },
            Properties = new GeoJsonProperties()
            {
                Name = "SomeName"
            }
        }));

        return Ok(jsonResult);
    }
```

This is the output:

```
{
"odata.metadata": "http://localhost:65372/odata/$metadata#GetGeoData_Result",
"value": [
  {
      "Type": "Feature",
      "Geometry": {
          "Type": "Polygon",
          "Coordinates": [
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {},     
            {},
            {}
          ]
      },
      "Properties": {
          "Name": "SomeName"
      }
```

}]
}

What am I doing wrong?